# DC Voltage Regulation 18V to 12V

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, dc

I'm implementing a voltage regulation circuit for some audio and video equipment. Input voltage can vary between 12V and 18V DC.

Currently using the [MC78T12C 3A regulator](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/4453/MOTOROLA/MC78T00/+3_W4uplRMROLDdRHD.bYv+/datasheet.pdf) but it's getting a little warm.

The unit is being powered by a 4C LiPo battery which presents 16.8VDC when fully charged. Seems that the 4.8V voltage drop may be a little bit too much for the regulator to manage.

At present the circuit isn't heatsinked, but this can be easily done.

Is this voltage drop too much for the regulator I am using or will a suitable heatsink solution be enough?

Comment: You don't mention current draw of the circuit?

Comment: Yeah, what's the current?  Then one can calculate the power in that 4.8V drop that will come out as heat.

Comment: The answer will probably turn into an DC/DC step down converter for high efficiency / low dissipation.

Comment: As this is a battery operated device, I'd seriously think about getting a specialised circuit for this - just as jippie suggested. You'll have a much better efficiency, and thus battery life.

Answer (score 4):

With heatsinking, your solution will indeed work. However, bear in mind that the minimum headroom needed by your regulator is 2.2V above the desired output voltage. Once your LiPos discharge below 14.4V, your load circuitry will start to suffer.

Series resistors can help move some of the power out of the regulator but since they introduce a voltage drop will further reduce the available power you can get from the batteries.

A better choice for your application would be a [buck-boost converter](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3789), which would allow your LiPo to discharge below 12V and continue to provide energy to your load, and would operate much more efficiently than the lossy regulator.

If the end application 'needs' clean DC, you can use the buck-boost to make an intermediate voltage (say 15V) then post-regulate it with a linear regulator - it will cost you efficiency but still allow you to get more energy from the LiPos than a regulator alone.

Comment: Good choice of chip +1

Comment: I like LT stuff. They can be a little pricey but they tend to perform well.

Comment: price is the only issue in my book. They do the business.